# Split column in pandas of comma separated values but maintining the order

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following column in a dataframe:

```
column_1
en-us,en-en
pr,en-us,en-en,br
ar-ar,pr,en-en
```

I want to Split that column (this can be done with .str.split) but using .Split I will get:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4
en-us      en-en
pr         en-us      en-en      br
ar-ar      pr         en-en
```

And what I need is:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4
en-us      en-en      
en-us      en-en      br         pr
ar-ar      en-en                 pr
```

Is there any automatic way of doing this?

Comment: Why does the 3rd row in your results begin with `ar-ar`? Shouldn't it be blank as `en-us` doesn't exist in that row?

Comment: sorry for not explaining that. Actually, the third row could begin with any type of string. The key of what I want to do is to align repeated values in the same column (so en-en should appear always in column_2, and ar-ar should appear always in column_1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do by passing a list of dictionaries to the default `pd.DataFrame` constructor. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s.str.split(',').transform(lambda x: {k:k for k in x}).tolist())
```

yields

```
    r-ar    br  en-en   en-us   pr
0   NaN     NaN en-en   en-us   NaN
1   NaN     br  en-en   en-us   pr
2   ar-ar   NaN en-en   NaN     pr
```

Notice that it is trivial to reorder the data frame according to your needs, e.g.

```
>>> df[['en-en', 'en-us', 'br', 'pr']]
    en-en   en-us   br  pr
0   en-en   en-us   NaN NaN
1   en-en   en-us   br  pr
2   en-en   NaN     NaN pr
```

And if you want to have empty strings rather than `NaN`s, just use `.fillna()`

```
df[['en-en', 'en-us', 'br', 'pr']].fillna('')

    en-en   en-us   br  pr
0   en-en   en-us       
1   en-en   en-us   br  pr
2   en-en           pr
```

---

Explanation

Let's break down the following statement

```
s.str.split(',').transform(lambda x: {k:k for k in x}).tolist()
```

First of all, `s.str.split(',')` does what you already know: splits using `,` as separator. This yields the following series

```
0            [en-us, en-en]
1    [pr, en-us, en-en, br]
2        [ar-ar, pr, en-en]
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Now, we want to change each of these elements into a `{key:value}` structure. For that, we use `transform` passing a function to it:

```
s.str.split(',').transform(function)
```

where `function = lambda x: {k:k for k in x}`. So basically we will run this `func` for the input `[en-us, en-en]`, then for `[pr, en-us, en-en, br]`, etc. The output of this function is

```
0                 {'en-en': 'en-en', 'en-us': 'en-us'}
1    {'br': 'br', 'en-en': 'en-en', 'en-us': 'en-us...
2     {'en-en': 'en-en', 'ar-ar': 'ar-ar', 'pr': 'pr'}
```

Now, we just use `tolist()` to get a list of these values, and input that in the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor. The constructor knows how to deal with lists of dictionaries pretty well, and it assigns values based on the `keys` of the dictionaries for each row. Whenever no key/value is found for a row, it just uses `NaN`s

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Could you explain me what is going on behind that .transform please?

Comment: AMAZING. Understood the explanation completely. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Glad I could help !! Good coding ;}

Comment: sorry for reopening this, but now I tried to do the exact same thing with a dataframe that contains NaN values. After filling the NaN with 'NA', Python throws "Memory error". Any way to avoid this issue? Thanks

Comment: @Cibgks Hi cibgks, I think its better for you to open another question with a reproducible example. That way more people will look at it ;)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the advice :)